# Removing xml namespaces in C# restful web service returned string

Tags: c#, json, xml, rest, wcf

I am having restful API which is written in C# using dot net framework 4.5..Currently its working alright... i'm returning a result after a JSON conversion.. I'm expecting a pure JSON result... which i'm not getting currently..  I'm expecting simple solution to omit the string XMLNS at the root element where i return the JSON...
Result 
i'am getting:
[image: result]

My code :

```
public String GetAllSalesInvoices(string customer_id, string Startdate, string Enddate)
    {
        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

        string query = "SELECT * FROM sales_invoice WHERE customer_id =" + customer_id + " AND invoice_date BETWEEN '" + Startdate + "' AND '" + Enddate + "'";
        DataSet ds = conObj.execQuery(query);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = ds.Tables[0];


        List<sales_invoice> result = new List<sales_invoice>();

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            sales_invoice inv = new sales_invoice()
            {
                Invoice_id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["invoice_id"]),
                Invoice_date = Convert.ToString(dr["invoice_date"].ToString()),
                Customer_id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["customer_id"]),
                Product_id = Convert.ToInt32((dr["product_id"])),
                Time = Convert.ToString((dr["time"]).ToString()),
                Quantity = Convert.ToInt32((dr["quantity"])),
                Unit_of_measure = Convert.ToString(dr["unit_of_measure"]),
                Product_price = Convert.ToInt32((dr["product_price"])),
                Sub_total = Convert.ToInt32((dr["sub_total"])),
            };
            result.Add(inv);
        }
        string json=serializer.Serialize(result);
        return json;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm expecting some code you wrote... Please update your question.

Comment: Are you using web api? If so - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847564/how-do-i-get-asp-net-web-api-to-return-json-instead-of-xml-using-chrome

Comment: No i am having restful web service@Steve

Comment: If you are not using web api then what are you using?  [tag:wcf]?

Comment: yes i am using wcf rest @dbc

Comment: Your problem is that you are double-serializing your `result`: first you serialize to a JSON string and then WCF serializes the string to XML.  Instead, let WCF serialize your `result` for you by simply returning it directly.  Then if you want to configure WCF to return JSON see maybe [How to return Json from WCF Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1830459/3744182) or [WCF REST return single method as JSON and XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15060089/3744182).

Comment: Thanks mate.. Got it fixed thanks to you... @dbc

Comment: Make it an answer then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159195/discussion-between-selaka-nanayakkara-and-dbc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys i finally managed to come up with an answer for removing the xml namespaces or string namespaces in return.
Solution is to use the context method and write content directly to browser it self. For that you can use this code.

```
String result =js.Serialize(data);
this.Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
this.Context.Response.Write(result);
```

This will write json serialized raw data in to the browser without any namespaces. Note that it cannot be used in context of restful api as the this might be different there.